# How to transpose every nth cell horizontally onto another Sheet vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

This combination of transposing and referencing I can't seem to figure out. On Sheet2 I have the following Data which is the original reference source. The data is every 8th cell in my example

```
D4:22  L4:16  T4:10
```

I'd then like to have on Sheet1 which is referenced to the respective cells on Sheet2

```
F6:22  F7:16 F8:10
```

There is data between the numbers on Sheet2 so I am unable to just collect all the data in a row and minus the empty cells which I know how to do. I'd like to drag down F6 which is the part I realize I've created my formula wrong because it doesn't drag down. The data on Sheet2 goes on for a hundreds of cells which is why I can't just create a simple `=Sheet2!D4`

Comment: Shoot I just realized I mistyped my example. The pattern is every 8th Cell on Sheet 2. That's probably why I'm being downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` to get the cells you want

Something like (For cell `Sheet1!F6`)

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$4:$4,1,ROW()*8-44)
```

And copy down

Comment: This is correct! Took me a minute to figure out how to apply it to my actual data but this is the right starting point!